# JQuery onchange in tabs event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to fire an event when I change from one tab to the other in JQuery?

for example:

```
<li><a href="#tab-1" onclick="submitForm();" onchange="myJSHere();">Tab</a></li>
```

Comment: The jQuery UI Tabs widget? Your JavaScript code makes no sense in terms of syntax by the way.

Comment: You're not new here, you should know to give more information and define exactly what you want.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

jQuery ui ???

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert("PRESSED TAB!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Hilariously, this callback happens *before* the actual tab change event occurs. I had to work around this by wrapping my *actual* callback in a setTimeout :(

Comment: Maybe you could use the "activate" event, it says in the DOCS that it fires after animation is complete ;-)

Answer (score 18):

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ activate: function(event ,ui){
                    //console.log(event);
                    //alert(  ui.newTab.index());
        alert( ui.newTab.attr('li',"innerHTML")[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML);
        //alert( this.text);
                } });
```

Answer (score 8):

Work for me

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>HOME</h3>
            <p>Some content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 1</h3>
            <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
            <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        activate: function(event, ui) {
            alert("PRESSED TAB!");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

My Solution is Click Event Listener.

**Solution:**

```
$('.nav-tabs li').click(function () { 
  alert('Tab Clicked');
});
```

**Complete Solution with HTML.**

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            <h3>HOME</h3>
            <p>Some content.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 1</h3>
            <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>Menu 2</h3>
            <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.nav-tabs li').click(function () { 
  alert('Tab Clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounter an issue with jquery accordion inside tabs not displaying properly (especially after manipulating the contents of the accordion. The below snipper does the trick. The commented line is just in case you wish to re-create the accordion entirely.

```
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            activate: function(event, ui) {

                // $( ".accordion" ).accordion('destroy').accordion().accordion( "refresh" );
                $( ".accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
            }
        });
```