# Flot plotting library for jQuery generated plot in not visible in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I use plugin jquery flot http://www.flotcharts.org/ and bootstrap tabs

When I put div to generate flot in tab which is now not vissible and wanted to generate him in $(document).ready(function(){}) in console show me error:

Invalid dimensions for plot, width = 0, height = 280

JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var chart_plot_01_settings = {...}, arr_data1 = ..., arr_data2 = ...;
    $.plot( $("#chart"), [ arr_data1, arr_data2 ],  chart_plot_01_settings );
})
```

Comment: can you add some code. so it will be easy to understand and answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null for flot charts api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719522/uncaught-invalid-dimensions-for-plot-width-null-height-null-for-flot-chart)

Comment: I find solution!
I should change to:
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $.plot( $("#chart"), [ arr_data1, arr_data2 ],  chart_plot_01_settings );
 })
After this plot will be paint after change tab:)
Thank you for help!

Comment: @KamilWyremski If found solution create a answer and post code there rather than code in comments

Comment: @wolfgang1983 - ok, thank you for info!

Answer (score 0):

I finded solution! I should change my code to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var chart_plot_01_settings = {...}, arr_data1 = ..., arr_data2 = ...;
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) { 
        $.plot( $("#chart"), [ arr_data1, arr_data2 ], chart_plot_01_settings ); 
    }) 
})
```

After this plot will be paint after user change tab - thank you for help!