# Call dirty form check when tab called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a window.onbeforeunload check for dirty form that works well.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    'use strict';
    if (isDirty === 1) {
        return 'You have unsaved changes';
    }
};
```

I would like to call this when users click on a tab, our tab call look like the following

```
<li><a href="#scheduling-tab" onclick="return schedulingTabGet('CRFilingScheduling.do', null);">Scheduling</a></li>
```

The schedulingTabGet code is in another file it is as follows:

```
function schedulingTabGet(url, formId) {
    return getTab('#scheduling-tab', url, formId);
}

function getTab(tabId, url, formId) {
    jQuery.get(url, jQuery(formId).serialize(), function (data) {
        jQuery(tabId).html(data);
    });

    return false;
}
```

I tried the code sample from [JQuery onchange in tabs event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928314/jquery-onchange-in-tabs-event) but it wouldn't work.  I am not sure if that is a little different case.
Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UI Tabs widget? That's what the answer i the other question requires.

Comment: Yes I think we are using jQuery-ui-1.9.0.  We include the following two files in the code jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js, and custom-plugins-jquery-ui-1.9.0-compatible.js.

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkDirty () {
    'use strict';
    if (isDirty === 1) {
        return 'You have unsaved changes';
    }
};

window.onbeforeunload = checkDirty;

function schedulingTabGet(url, formId) {
    var msg = checkDirty();
    if (msg && confirm(msg)) {
        return getTab('#scheduling-tab', url, formId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this out but it didn't work. The schedulingTabGet and the getTab are in a separate file from the main jsp.  If I move it into the one jsp it would work.